# НЕ слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Не с причастием пишется раздельно, если есть зависимое слово. А если это причастие перешло в существительное? Тогда как? 
У Розенталя нашла:

*Этому также подчиняются причастия, употребляемые в роли существительных, например: В числе не явившихся на заседание были Петров и Сергеев. Но при субстантивации причастия (переходе в разряд существительных) используется слитное написание, например: число неуспевающих по русскому языку.*

Как отличить *причастия, употребляемые в роли существительных,*от *субстантивированных* *причастий?* И правильно ли тогда написано название фильма "Неспящие в Сиэтле"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, субстантивированные причастия окончательно теряют признак глагольности. Они характеризуют сам объект напрямую, а не опосредовано через действие, им выполняемое.

Часто различить невозможно. Но без "НЕ" практической необходимости в этом не возникает.

Comment: Спасибо.Это я понимаю. Получается, формальных отличий нет, все на уровне "языкового чутья". А если вернуться к Розенталевским примерам. Часть речи в первом предложении - причастие? Без главного слова? Или определяемое слово можем считать опущенным (типа неполное предложение?)

Comment: >>>Часть речи в первом предложении - причастие? Без главного слова?  

Думаю, да. "Главного слова", понятно, не требуется, здесь же причастие не в своей обычной роли выступает. А существительное в причущей ему роли (лополнения и подлежащего) такого слова отнбдь не требует. Так что формальных причин отказыватся от признания "не явившихся" причастие нет.

Comment: Но строго доказывать, что это именно причастие, я не берусь. Только косвенно. На основании того, что это разовое свойство, по однократному действию. В то время как "учащиеся" - это свойство  постоянное, состояние, связанное не столько с самим процессом учения, сколько с социальным статусом.   

>>>Или определяемое слово можем считать опущенным (типа неполное предложение?)  
  
Нет. Точно нет. Тогда бы оно не было "в роли существительного".

Comment: Спасибо. Я согласна. Где бы еще научный источник по теме найти.

Comment: Вот тут - не помогу. Я ж "сам себе Розеталь" (©не я).

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, как сам Розенталь их различал?

Перелопатила интернет, но ответа на свой вопрос не нашла.

Comment: Спасибо, Элен. Напишу, до чего сама додумалась.

Comment: К субстантивированным причастиям и прилагательным можно подобрать определения: "Мнимый больной", хмурые неуспевающие...  А вот можно ли определенения подобрать к причастиям, употребляемым в роли сужествительных?